# Publishing Layout - Custom Master page

Tags: publishing-page, sharepoint-designer, 2007

I've been slowing catching on to the Publishing pages functionality. I'm still a bit confused on the creation of Publishing Types (such as Page, Page Layout and Publishing Master page)

The issue I'm running into is specifying on a specific page layout what master page to use. By going through the site settings, I can change the entire site's master page, but ideally what I would like to do is:
- Create a Publishing Master page layout (custom.master)
- Create the Page Layout that uses the above master page (customLayout.aspx)
- Create a page from the web admin, that will allow me to use the pre-defined regions of the customLayout.aspx

This all seems pretty forward, but even creating a new layout wasn't intuitive, as you had to first declare it as a new content type and create a new page based on it.
Here's MS's tutorial on it: 
[Create a Publishing page layout](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-publishing-page-layout-HA010174128.aspx)

As you can see in their tutorial, we're using the  "page" parent type, but it's later on used to create a layout? I guess there's a disconnect.

There is no indication as to how the master page can be associated with the page's layout and adding the masterpage type entry to the .aspx page did absolutely nothing.

Any help (and explanation) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master page in SharePoint publishing site is set on a web level , Once you set the master page,all the publishing master page will use the custom master page.So if you check [SPWeb.CustomMasterUrl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.custommasterurl.aspx)

P.S there are 2 types of page in a site , site page and application page.If you would like to brand application page you need to set the [SPWeb.MasterUrl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.masterurl.aspx)

Page layout
You can regard Page layout as page template,it will control your UI.The reason the page layout binds to contentType is that for the same data you can present them in a different manner(using different page layout)

Comment: Thanks for the information and explanation - I'm used to setting up simple master templates and being able to completely change the look and feel by attaching different master templates. I guess that's what the page layouts are there for.
I had setup the site page to use my new master template, which worked, just got to wonder what the point of the publishing master template content type was, if you couldn't do much with it. I can't even associated the publishing master template I've defined with an actual file. Any idea what it's used for?